# how to get the data from captcha in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium webdriver (Java).

I need to test the registration form but before submitting, image box (captcha) is appearing but everytime of execution it is going to be changed. I want to know how to get the data from image (captcha).

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 16):

If the captcha is coming from an environment under your control, you will likely need to implement some sort of method indicating you are in a test environment and have the captcha system return a known value or some indicator of what the expected value is.

If, on the other hand, the captcha is coming from another source out of your control, you are probably our of luck.  At that point, you are essentially in the same boat as the spammers who are in a constant arms race to write software that can visually parse a captcha.

**UPDATE**

I feel the need to add some clarification to the ideas put forth in the question, answer and comments.  Essentially you are dealing with one of the following situations (note that when I say 'your', I am referring to you, your company, client, etc):

1) Your form, Your captcha system: If this is the case, your best solution is to work with your developers to add a 'test' mode to your captchas, returning either a known value, or additional information in the page that indicates what the expected value should be.  If you are able to make use of a tool, either written by you, or by another, that can successfully 'read' the captcha image, your system is broken.  If you can do it in test mode, what is to stop anyone else (spammer, hacker, etc) from bypassing your captcha in exactly the same manner.

2) Your form, 3rd Party captcha system: If this is the case, your best solution is again to see if the system has some 'test' mode that you can make use of.  I have no experiance with these systems myself but in general would guess that test methods exist for the major systems out there.  A Google search of *{Captcha System Name} automated testing* should return some good hints as to how to go about testing with the system.  If nothing good comes from that, your next bet would be to implement your own, internal, test only, dummy captcha system that works with some known value and make your captcha provider configurable so that you can point to your test system in test/dev/etc and your real system in production.

3) Another Form, Unknown captcha system: I am going to make a leap of faith here and assume this is not your case, but just for completeness I will include it.  If this is your case, your not testing anything at all and are simply asking for help bypassing someone else's security mechanisms for your own reasons.  If that is the case, please seek your assistance on less scrupulous sites.

Comment: I want to know what method will use to get the value from image (captcha)

Comment: If there is any hope of figuring out the value, the first step would be knowing what Captcha system you are using.  Could you update your question with which Captcha system you are calling?  There is always a chance the developers will have included a testing option that you can make use of.

Comment: I'm getting the new image (captcha) with text on webpage. (it is not repeating) How to know about what Captcha system you are using?

Comment: Check with the developers or have them put a single captcha for all requests

Comment: After searching a lot over google and other website. I reached on the point that captcha (image) can be readable using iMicros.
Image Recogination tool is available to find the data from code during selenium.

Comment: Yes, but if it is readable, then it has failed at beIng CAPTCHA. Raise a bug against the system!

Comment: @SATENDRA, the point is you are essentially trying to break the CAPTCHA that you are using to help secure your site. If you can do it, what's stopping others from doing it? Thus, as Mike pointed out, you will need to work with your dev's to implement something where it's disabled for your test environment. Perhaps there is a database configuration value you can change on the fly, to disable it only when your tests are running, etc etc. Trying to "read" the CAPTCHA is never going to work.

Answer (score 2):

Captcha code was introduced in order to prevent from the robot or automation codes. There is no option for automating the Captcha code.

**1 . You can give a wait time for the automation, so that the user can enter the captcha code.**

**2. If the project is in testing url means, you can request your system admin and developer to disable the captcha validation.**

May be this can help you, but i din't try on this..

Developers will generate a random value for captcha, and they will convert the value into image as well as they will store the value in session for comparing the entered input is matching with the captcha code.

So If possible, you can take that session value and give as the input.