# Protractor - How to skip testing of captcha while signup?

Tags: testing, captcha, protractor

I have are you human captcha in my signup form. How can i skip it in testing?

Could any one suggest how to skip captcha testing while registering the user?

Comment: Related: [how to get the data from captcha in selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933178/how-to-get-the-data-from-captcha-in-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: @alecxe, the captcha what we are using needs human interaction. Here we are not asking to write text. It is like identifying the items from set of random things.

Comment: You need to use browser.switchTo().frame(0);

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294284/angularjs-e2e-test-with-angular-recaptcha)