# Angularjs, e2e test with angular-recaptcha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm actually trying to e2e test my simple application and I m having some troubles dealing with angular-recaptcha (https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha).

Here's my test :

```
  it('should redirect on another page', function() {

    browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/');
    var userName = element(by.model('auth.loginInfos.username'));
    userName.sendKeys('consumer1@eco.com');

    var password = element(by.model('auth.loginInfos.password'));
    password.sendKeys('consumer1');



    var recapt = element(by.id('recaptcha'));
    recapt.sendKeys();/* How can I put the recaptcha value to true ? */

    var btn = element(by.className('btn'));
    btn.click();
    /**
     * Assertions etc...
     */

  });
```

So, you can see that I m trying to fill the recaptcha value and I don't know how to proceed.

Can you help me ?

*NB: I m using protractor*

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The captcha is loaded in an `iframe`, you need to switch to it before trying to check:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(0);
```

where `0` is a frame index. You can use a frame name, id or a previously found frame element.

Sample test that uses the recaptcha demo page:

```
"use strict";

describe("Recaptcha", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get("http://vividcortex.github.io/angular-recaptcha/");
    });

    it("should click the captcha", function () {
        browser.switchTo().frame(0).then(function () {
            var checkbox = $(".recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark");

            // first hover the checkbox
            browser.actions().mouseMove(checkbox).perform();

            // hardcoded delay
            browser.sleep(500);

            // okat, now click - TODO: may be we should click with browser.actions().click() and provide the x, y coordinates for where to click
            checkbox.click();
        });

        // expectations
    });
});
```

Note that in my case, after the click, it asks to select certain images that would exactly do the job of not letting my selenium automation bot pass the test. If you want to actually pass the captcha, according to the [How does new Google reCAPTCHA work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286232/how-does-new-google-recaptcha-work) page and the known information about how this captcha works, I would try the following things:

- open the browser with a pre-loaded profile that you've used before (that has the browsing history, at least)
- be logged into google account in the browser fired up for testing
- don't click the checkbox via `click()` and click it with an offset as a regular human would do
- play around with a delays between browser actions

---

Another point is that, you don't need to e2e test how the captcha works - it is out of scope of the end-to-end testing of your application. Find a way to disable/turn the captcha off for the testing users, or for a specific build that you will be running tests against.

Comment: *Find a way to disable/turn the captcha off for the testing users* The question is how to do that?

Comment: Don't forget to [use testing keys](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#what-happens-to-recaptcha-v1) that allow robots to click and pass the "I'm not a robot" test.