# AngularJS e2e test case with Protractor failed with Google Captcha

Tags: angularjs, protractor, recaptcha, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test my application and there is a sign-up page for the e2e test case and a Google recaptcha within the sign-up form.

I tried to use the below code to bypass Google recaptcha code:

```
    browser.switchTo().frame(0).then(function () {
        console.log("Inside iFrame ");
        var checkbox = $(".recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark");
        browser.sleep(5000);
        console.log("var checkbox defined.");
        // first hover the checkbox
        browser.actions().mouseMove(checkbox).perform();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        console.log("Moved mouse to hover on checkbox");
        // hardcoded delay
        browser.sleep(500);
        browser.sleep(5000);
        console.log("Browser sleep completed.");
        // okat, now click - TODO: may be we should click with browser.actions().click() and provide the x, y coordinates for where to click
        checkbox.click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        console.log("clicked checkbox.");
    });
```

I got this code from the Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35294284/angularjs-e2e-test-with-angular-recaptcha).

However, using this code has produced the following error:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details.

Moreover, I put in debugging console logs and whilst they are printing successfully I am still given the error.

Comment: instead of `checkbox.click()` use `browser.actions().mouseMove(checkbox).click().perform();`

Comment: I tried but got the same error :(

Comment: share your html and ui to get a better view on the problem