# Wait until login button is manually clicked in selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

Is it possible in Selenium Webdriver to pause the code execution using `webdriver.wait` until the user clicks the login button for a form?
The form contains a Captcha that the user has to manually fill in, so I can't automatically click the button using the script.
The login button on click returns the value of a JavaScript function in the form of Boolean value i.e either true or false.

Any possible solution for this problem?

Comment: I think a better approach is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28883339/600486 - btw, do a search on SO and you will get plenty of suggestions

Comment: The problem isn't with the captcha, I am looking for a solution wherein the code pauses until a definite condition is met which in this situation is when the user clicks the login button.
Thanks for the suggestion btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: completely new response after getting more info.

With the code below, this is what happens:

1. Selenium enters the user data
2. I then manually refresh the page (because I don't have login data to test)
3. Selenium enters the user data again

*(the variable W is an earlier defined `WebDriverWait`.)*

```
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf");

        // will try looping as long as you're on the relevant page
        do
        {
            try
            {
                IWebElement username = w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("usernameId")));
                IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Name("j_password"));
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(username.GetAttribute("value")))
                {
                    username.SendKeys("a");
                    password.SendKeys("b");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { 
                // page is reloading, just wait another round
            }
        } while (!String.Equals(driver.Url, "put url after login here"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
The situation I'm facing here is that when the user visits the login page, his credentials are automatically filled. In the case when the user types in the wrong captcha the page refreshes and he has to manually type in his credentials. I want to avoid this situation for which I required a condition which I could make use of to perform some type of check.

I was wondering if its possible to get the value of a JS function present on the webpage? Could make use of it to achieve the above mentioned functionality.

Comment: Selenium fills in the credentials. Then Selenium waits for a condition, which in this case sounds like "wait until the credential fields are empty again". Then you manually fill in the wrong captcha. Selenium finds the empty fields and continues execution. Or do I still not understand properly?

Comment: Selenium fills in the credentials, waits till the user enters the captcha and click the login button manually. If the user fails to enter the correct captcha the page reloads but this time selenium fails to fill in the details again because the code execution has left the login code block.
Is it possible for selenium to fill in the details every time the page refreshes?

Comment: Use a WHILE loop on the credential fields. For example, as long as the captcha is visible, have Selenium try filling in the credentials if they're empty. Just remember to put a bit of a wait so the While doesn't execute hundreds of times a second. Does that help?

Comment: Just tried this approach, the problem with this is that if the user enters the correct captcha and then clicks the login button after the wait time has expired, the while loop executes again and selenium uses the login code in the new page that appears after successful login which in this case fails and the script aborts.

Comment: Do you have a URL on which I can test and write out an example? I think it should be possible with the right condition for the While loop.

Comment: This is the [link](https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf) @Frederik De Mets

Comment: Your solution did the job! :D
Had to change the code a bit because Java wasn't supporting some of the keywords or methods. Plus I had to remove the `wait.until` for username because if a condition comes up where the loop iterated again while the new page was loading, the wait will continue for ever and the rest of the code won't run.

Comment: Good to hear. :) By the way, all questions related to Selenium can also be asked at the sqa.stackexchange community.