# Captcha handling using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, captcha, recaptcha

I am trying to automate one form where I get re-Captcha as a part of form submission. I got stuck and figuring out that how can we handle the captcha text using selenium webdriver. Though this captcha is turing test implementation in realtime but, still I am finding some way so that I can handle this scenario.

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933178/how-to-get-the-data-from-captcha-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Just use thread.sleep method with 10 seconds when web driver reach at captcha field , enter captcha manuallly and then web driver will continue execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can't really do that, captcha is by definition meant to break your automation. That said, I have had some luck using [Tesseract OCR](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/), but I was dealing with rather simplistic ones that contained only numbers. While I was doing that, I also looked into some javascript based solutions, but I was unable to achieve any success with those. I think it is worth giving a try, but most probably you are out of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new [Google unobtrusive reCaptcha v3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), the back end call to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` returns a score value between 0 (100% Bot) and 1.0 (100% human). You can choose the threshold level of 'humanity' and, can move this threshold into environment-specific configurations.

e.g. What we do is set a threshold value of around 0.7 in our production system, but in our development environments where we run our Selenium tests, we set this threshold to 0 in order to allow our Se tests to verify the functional correctness of our external facing forms.

We have also run a Selenium smoke test against our production environment (where the threshold is 0.7) to ensure that the Captcha is correctly configured and does prevent abuse.

Comment: I'm trying to do a Smoke Test with Selenium in my implementation locally, but siteverify returns score with 0.9, as if a human is interacting. I'm a little confused about this.