# How to work with captcha in automation with selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium and have come accross a point where there is a need to write a script to register for new users for a website.
But the challenge is of a confirmation check box 'i am not a robot' where the captcha asks the user to select different image with same context(say image having cars)
Can you please confirm if this can be automated?
If yes then what should be the approach for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Captcha handling using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466687/captcha-handling-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with test cases:

1. One test that should prove that captcha protects against robots.
2. A second one that proves that captcha works when it's filled up by a human.
3. Should prove that if the captcha recognized a human (quality of this is out of scope in point 3), app will show expected result page.

If these test 2. could be automated then the captcha will give no value (it would mean that you can prepare a robot which acts as a human so anyone can do that).
But you should, of course, test your application against case 1.

So, in my opinion, the only one way how your selenium test can proceed with registration test, is to work around the captcha (turn it off).

For this purpose, one of the possible solutions is to let the backend store in a file (could ba log) some random token which must be sent by your selenium test to the backend from web browser (in a cookie or as a request parameter). If backend received a correct token, it should ignore captcha result.

Depending on risk acceptance (depends on the business supported by your app), this workaround should be turned off on production (and also tested during deployment if it's turned off).